# Which is more logical & better performing? One CI App or multiple CI apps

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter app in a git repo. Currently i deploy a new installation on my server for each new client i signup.

Each new client has its own database and its own files in a folder such as: `/var/www/vhosts/example.com/client/client1/`

Each client gets a subdomain that i map out through plesk. `client1.example.com`.

**My question:** 
Is it better performing to have a single app setup to manage all of these client installations with different database.php config files.

IE: `/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/*`

and use a htaccess redirect for the sub domains to remap the URI to different configs.

Or is it better performing to have a seperate installation for each client like i listed above.

#### Server Information:

- PHP 5.3
- MySQL 5.x
- CodeIgniter 2.1
- WireDesignz HMVC
- Sparks (various)
- CentOS DV4 from MediaTemple

Comment: to further clarify, these clients are allowed basic CSS customization and logo customization. Outside of that the site is cookie cutter and the codebase does not change between clients. They pay a subscription fee for us to house and manage the app for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say keep them apart.

Each client will have their own set of requirements. While the Server won't change that much , your code base will. It will become hard over time NOT to break something for one client while building something for another.

As they will be separate projects you'll be able to move larger sites away from the smaller sites. But this depends on what type of traffic you're clients receive.

And having each Application in it's own Repository (You are using Version Control, Right ?) would make your world that much more organized.

Performance wise the smaller application designed for a client, and only running what they want will probably outperform one monolithic site serving all your clients any day.

Hope I understood that correctly, it's my personal opinion.

Comment: i realize the question is opinionated, trying to get the facts and not opinions just to conform with SO's rules. However thanks for your input ... +1